# Connection between Playframework and ExtJs

Tags: extjs, playframework, extjs4, extjs3

I am doing a project were I am trying to make the backend with playframework and the frontend with Extjs.

I can retrieve the data from the server with Json and show it in a grid with all it's fields.

The problem comes when I try to modify, remove or add any record.

The request sent by Ext: DELETE lista?_dc=1318409614652

(I solved _dc with "noCache: false" over the proxy)

The request right now is: DELETE lista

The request I need is: DELETE lista/"parameter of the object like ID or name"

Do you have any idea about this? If you need any information let me know

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just for reference, the dc caching parameter may cause issues for you later on if the server decides to start caching your AJAX requests, is it really a problem to keep the parameter on there?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are not yet using the [Rest proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest) (of ExtJS) for this, but you should, as it does exactly what you are asking for. You set it up with an url like `/lista` in your case. Now, when you delete a record, the proxy automatically sends a `DELETE` request to the url, appending it with the id. Check out the documentation (linked above) for more info - you can control the url generation a little bit, but in your case it looks like you can do with the default options.

Answer (score 0):

even if you don't want to use Rest Proxy, you use still use Ext.Ajax.request like below.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        waitMsg: "Saving... Please wait",
        url: "myserverscript.php",
        method: "POST",
        params: {
            action: "delete",
            id: myForm.down('#id').getValue(),
            data: jsonData
        }
});
```